# Too many “and”s - separating clauses vs. list items

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, lists

I have the following sentence and feel like my usage of “and” is awkward since it makes it look like a list of three things:

> The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet and related changes and technologies like digital journalism and social media, respectively.

I hope it’s clear the structure is like {(thanks to the internet) AND [(related changes) AND (technologies)]}. How to rephrase or fix the sentence?

Comment: It isn't clear what "related changes" actually refers to. Is it changes to the internet or changes to technology? Is "digital journalism" actually a technology at all? It seems more like an application of technology to me.

Comment: The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet, with its related changes, and technologies like digital journalism and social media. The word *respectively* is superfluous.

Comment: Use a comma. 'The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet, and related changes and technologies like digital journalism and social media' or a 'small intimate and' 'The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet, and related changes & technologies like digital journalism and social media' //A duplicate, but it's lunchtime.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than “and”, perhaps using the phrase “as well as” would avoid the confusion. It would also eliminate the need to use the word “respectively”.

> The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet and related changes as well as technologies like digital journalism and social media.

Comment: Now without "respectively" though, both digital journalism and social media refer to the technologies. What I want is for "digital journalism" to refer to "related changes" and for "social media" to refer to "technologies". But it did give me an idea:
"The scale of the problem has only become greater thanks to the internet and related changes to, for example, digital journalism, as well as new technologies, prime example of which is social media."
How does this work?